# Is this spring code thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, hibernate

This class is designed to run in a Spring Boot controller. The admin data lives in an Oracle table, and there is only one record of it. This is needed because the data could be changed by another application and, if it does, this app needs to read the new data.

So AdminData is an entity bean (Hibernate). In practice, the admin data will almost never be updated, but this is a high volume web application so that data is read very frequently. It's needed on every call to GET and POST.

I considered using AtomicReference<> but in this case I'm not sure it's any better than just using the volatile keyword.

I am thinking this is thread safe because:

1 - The get() method just returns a reference, and in Java fetching or updating a reference is atomic.

2 - The onDatabaseChangeNotification() call is probably not going to execute atomically because of the call to the repository, but this method can only ever be executed by a call from Oracle, so there would only be one thread ever running it. Again, the reference assignment to cachedAd should be atomic.

3 - I'm thinking that the call to setInitialValue() probably will only ever be executed by one thread as well, but I'm not sure so I added the synchronized.

Am I right? Thanks for your help.

```
@DependsOn("DecLogger")
@Service
public class AdminDataCacher implements DatabaseChangeListener 
{
    @Autowired
    private AdminDataRepository adRep;

    private volatile AdminData cachedAd = null;

    public AdminData get()
    {
        return cachedAd;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDatabaseChangeNotification(oracle.jdbc.dcn.DatabaseChangeEvent e) 
    {
        cachedAd = adRep.findByKey(1L);
        DecLogger.DEC_LOGIN.finer(() -> "Oracle DCN Call on Admin Data - Invalidating Cached Data");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private synchronized void setInitialValue()
    {
        cachedAd = adRep.findByKey(1L);
        DecLogger.DEC_LOGIN.finer(() -> "AdminDataCacher - Initial value set");
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**, based on comments and some sleep:

If AdminData were not threadsafe and could not be made threadsafe (by making it immutable) perhaps this approach would work, although I am concerned about performance:

```
    public AdminData get()
    {
        AdminData tmp = cachedAd;

        return tmp.clone();
    }
```

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

Based upon more comments and more research, I have rewritten the class.

I decided that what I need is an immutable object to hold the administrative data, so I created an additional, immutable class called AdminDataImmutable. This class, since it is immutable, is inherently threadsafe so I can return it to every caller, thus avoiding the overhead of cloneing the cached instance and I won't have to worry about another developer misusing it in the future, and I won't have to defend / protect copies out of it.

When the database changes, as pointed out, I should synchronize on the repository, and I can update the reference for the cached object without concern because, in Java, reference update is atomic by design.

So now, in the get() method, I can simply return the reference. Code below. Does this new version make sense???

Thanks!

```
@DependsOn("DecLogger")
@Service
public class AdminDataCacher implements DatabaseChangeListener 
{
    private volatile AdminDataImmutable cachedAd;

    @Autowired
    private AdminDataRepository adRep;

    public AdminDataImmutable get()
    {
        return cachedAd;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDatabaseChangeNotification(oracle.jdbc.dcn.DatabaseChangeEvent e) 
    {
        DecLogger.DEC_LOGIN.finer(() -> "Oracle DCN Call on Admin Data - Invalidating Cached Data");

        synchronized(adRep)
        {
            AdminDataEntity ade = adRep.findByKey(1L);
            cachedAd = new AdminDataImmutable(ade);
        }   
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void loadInitialValue()
    {
        synchronized(adRep)
        {
            AdminDataEntity ade = adRep.findByKey(1L);
            cachedAd = new AdminDataImmutable(ade);
        }
    }
}
```

**LAST UPDATE**

I made cachedAd volatile.

Comment: New version using `AdminDataImmutable` looks reasonable.

Comment: I'm wondering if I need the volatile on cachedAd? Since it is only ever updated from inside this class, the optimizer should know how to handle it from a thread visibility standpoint. What do you think?

Comment: Oops!  You're right.  If different threads are calling the get() method, then cachedAd probably should be volatile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose `volatile AdminData` is useless here, because this only secure updating of reference, but not making `AdminData` object thread safe itself. And as you mentioned about `get()` method, in java updating of references are always atomic operation. So you try to oversecure reference. If you want to be sure that AdminData object are threadsafe by itself, you should review code of AdminData object.

About 2) and 3) I would notice that may be it is worth to take a look on code of `findByKey` method and make it thread safe, but not try to assume number on caller threads (seems like you are not sure in both cases). Try to make thread safe code as high by stack as it possible - it will decrease number of critical sections and reduce code complexity.

If you can not rework or review code of AdminDataRepository, then in case of 2) you assume that only one caller will be. But by analogy with 3) may be worth to add `synchronized` to be sure, because it is still possible that `findByKey` will be called by at least two threads at the same time one: at least one call from not threadsafe `onDatabaseChangeNotification()` (but there could be more threads) and one call from synchronized `setInitialValue()`. So you secure one method, but still could get two concurrency calls to `findByKey()`. It can cause problems in case `findByKey()` interacts with some shared data in adRep object, not just retrieve data from Oracle database (As simple example just imagine that every call of `findByKey` increment some internal counter, which is shared across all calls).

Next, just putting `synchronized` on method `onDatabaseChangeNotification()` has one more pitfall. In this case, you are using `this` object (`AdminDataCacher` object) as lock object and it will secure in case `AdminDataRepository adRep` are injected only in `AdminDataCacher`. But if the same singelton object `AdminDataRepository adRep` will be injected in some class - you are in trouble, because `synchronized` is useless, you could still get several calls to `adRep.findByKey()` at the same time (one from `AdminDataCacher` and some more from other classes where `AdminDataRepository adRep` are injected). In this case you should secure on `adRep` object:

```
@Override
public void onDatabaseChangeNotification(oracle.jdbc.dcn.DatabaseChangeEvent e) 
{
    synchronized(adRep) {
        cachedAd = adRep.findByKey(1L);
    }
    DecLogger.DEC_LOGIN.finer(() -> "Oracle DCN Call on Admin Data - Invalidating Cached Data");
}

@PostConstruct
private void setInitialValue()
{
    synchronized(adRep) {
        cachedAd = adRep.findByKey(1L);
    }
    DecLogger.DEC_LOGIN.finer(() -> "AdminDataCacher - Initial value set");
}
```

Sorry for too many letter, but I try to give you an idea how to analyse code and choose correct decision. So, in conclusion step by step:

1. Try to make `AdminDataRepository` object threadsafe and call it
   without `synchronized`
2. If it is not possible use object `adRep` as
   lock
3. Use `AdminData` object without `volatile`, but it is also
   worth to review its internal code

   P.S. This info are valid in case of plain Java. I'm not 100% sure that Spring does not have some internal logic to make calls to a bean thread safe.

Comment: You're absolutely right about AdminData itself being threadsafe. Let's assume for a second that it is not, but I think it is. Originally I was returning a clone of it. As for the repository, I think I'm better off fetching the entity to a temporary variable, then assigning the reference of the temp to cached cahcedAd.  That should be atomic. I believe volatile is needed for visibility. Also, I avoided using AtomicReference because I was not sure if it blocks. I'm trying to avoid blocking wherever possible. I need to go out the door, thank you, more later...

Comment: @JimArcher, I have take a look on your update and I suppose it does not helps you eliminate lock. It is still unclear for me why you are so aware about get method? Are you afraid that when you return AdminData object, some other thread would be modifing it and you return it in incorrect state? If so, then I would recommend you to secure writers, then readers with out any addtional effort will get correct object. And you do not need AtomicReference here, in java setting a reference is atomic operation by itself. AtomicReference is used in other cases.

Comment: As you say, in the get() method my concern is that the AdminData class has setters, and it needs them as a Spring Entity. I found an excellent discussion of this issue: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/VNA02-J.+Ensure+that+compound+operations+on+shared+variables+are+atomic  All my setters and getters appear to do nothing more than a set or a get, but because the object is an Spring Entity that may not be true, now or in the future. Safest bet seems to use locks, which will probably hurt performance. I could return a clone to each calling thread, but that may be worse.

Answer (score 0):

> 2 - The onDatabaseChangeNotification() call is probably not going to execute atomically because of the call to the repository, but this method can only ever be executed by a call from Oracle, so there would only be one thread ever running it.

That is not the right way of thinking about thread-safety.

Methods never need synchronization.  No matter how many threads call the same method in your program at the same time, nothing bad will ever happen to the *method*.

It's *data* that need synchronization.

Your `onDatabaseChangeNotification(...)` method calls `adRep.findByKey(1L)`.  What you need to think about is, what other threads could be accessing or modifying any of the same program state at the same time.  *That* is where you might run into trouble.

Comment: I'm thinking if I fetch the entity from the repository and assign it to a different, temporary instance of AdminData, and then assign the temporary reference to the cached value, I could eliminate the lock. The update of that reference should be atomic. Does that make sense.?

Comment: @JimArcher I don't know.  What is an "entity"?  If "fetch entity from the repository" is not an atomic operation, and if there's any way for one thread to be modifying an entity while another thread tries to "fetch" it, that probably would be bad.

Comment: @ James Well the call to the repository is probably not threadsafe, but the assignment of the reference it returns probably is. The setInitialValue() method is not really a concern. It's called before the framework is completely up, and before clients will connect, so there is no performance implication. The all to get() is most critical, and you're completely right about AdminData needing to be threadsafe or get() needing to return a new instance.

Comment: Based on comments and research, I have rewritten the class and updated the question with the new code. Comments welcome and very much appreciated!